# Google sheet formula that finds row name and returns column headers based on marked cells

Tags: google-sheets, formula

I'm trying to return the column headers for a row that is marked with an x. The row is selected from a name in the left column. I'm stuck here.

I can illustrate what I want to do by showing these images:
[Start table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GK2C3.png)

The result I want is this:
[Outputs of the possibilities for the first sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T8pTE.png)

I have put more information in my Example Sheet.

[Link to editable example sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Dzle-WOvY-WeUtPCd-ASdUL7VhMPf-QmMwcutSe1BZ8/edit#gid=0)

Comment: Have you tried anything thus far?

Comment: What am I missing? You are almost there. You don't _need_ the "Intermediate" column. Move those formula down to the output column of your "blue" table. That's how I created the range L18:L29 in your example spreadsheet-now you can delete column H. Any values that you add or delete in the "orange" table are reflected in the "blue" table. If you want, you could link the month names in column K to the respective values (names) in Column A. PS: This question (_as it stands_) doesn't deserve to be voted down.

Comment: You are missing the "month-search" in the join-filter-formula. The present forumula doesn't find the right row on its own. You must specify row in the formula right now.

Comment: You can find my progress in the supplied link above.

Comment: I need a way to move the filter condition based on "Month". Maybe it can be done with a query to filter out the unwanted cells?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This formula should create a table (with a single formula) with the months in one column and the headers in the second column.

```
=ArrayFormula({A4:A15\ substitute(transpose(query(transpose(if(B4:G15="x";B3:G3&char(10);));;rows(A4:A15)));" ";)})
```

If you'd want to 'lookup' the months you manually type in you can wrap the above in a vlookup. Example:

```
=ArrayFormula(if(len(L4:L); vlookup(L4:L; {A4:A15\ substitute(transpose(query(transpose(if(B4:G15="x";B3:G3&char(10);));;rows(A4:A15)));" ";)}; 2; 0);))
```

You can check out both formulas in the copy of the sheet I've made in the spreadsheet you shared.

Comment: Thanks. Looks like it works in the example sheet. I will look into it tomorrow. Exited! Hope it works. Now time to sleep. Late here in Sweden.